How do I get the Jacobian of numerical intengration-methods with half steps?
in my book, a series of proofs for numerical integration works with the definition
$$
F_\epsilon= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \tilde{t}}\left(\boldsymbol{X}_{i}, \boldsymbol{V}_{i}\right)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & \mathbb{I} \\ -\mathbb{I} & 0\end{array}\right] \cdot\binom{\partial \tilde{\mathscr{H}} / \partial \boldsymbol{X}_{i}}{\partial \tilde{\mathscr{H}} / \partial \boldsymbol{V}_{i}} \quad i=1, \ldots, 3 N
$$
But I am confused how to do this for integration methods with half time-steps, e.g $\epsilon + 1/2$. To be more precise, I want to understand a proof for the leapfrog integrator
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{X}_{j}(\tilde{t}+\epsilon / 2) & =\boldsymbol{X}_{j}(\tilde{t})+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \boldsymbol{V}_{j}(\tilde{t}) \\[1mm] \boldsymbol{V}_{j}(\tilde{t}+\epsilon) & =\boldsymbol{V}_{j}(\tilde{t})-\epsilon \frac{\partial U(\tilde{t}+\epsilon / 2)}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}_{j}} \\[1mm] \boldsymbol{X}_{j}(\tilde{t}+\epsilon) & =\boldsymbol{X}_{j}(\tilde{t}+\epsilon / 2)+\frac{\epsilon}{2} \boldsymbol{V}_{j}(\tilde{t}+\epsilon)
\end{align}
that says

Proof: In contrast to forward Euler, the DKD leapfrog integrator reads
with $\displaystyle\hat{X}:=X+\epsilon V / 2$
$\displaystyle F_{\epsilon}=\binom{X+\epsilon V-\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{2} A(\hat{X})}{V-\epsilon A(\hat{X})}$
for which
$\displaystyle\operatorname{det} \frac{\partial F_{\epsilon}}{\partial \xi}=1$  $

How does one come up with the Jacobian $F_\epsilon$ here? I thought about calculating a matrix for both steps, the half and the full one, but I dont see how this comes to one single matrix?
Thanks in advance.

This is not leapfrog Verlet, but velocity Verlet. Both are implementations of the same numerical path, but leapfrog has less local state variables inside the method loop. // What is $U$? And why is it a function of $t$ and not of $X$?

@LutzLehmann U is the potential part of the Hamiltonian H = T + U. It is indeed a function of X and I assume this is talking about U(X(t)), if this helps. Furthermore, this is described as the leapfrog integrator in my book

Then your book authors did not understand the context of the names. But that is not really important as the differences are superficial. Velocity Verlet can be seen as the combination of two symplectic Euler steps, one of each variants, and the variants are time-reversed to each other. This time-symmetric structure can be used to find the Jacobian in a more systematic form.

On the symplectic nature of the symplectic Euler step, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749759/proving-that-the-semi-implicit-euler-method-is-symplectic/4750382#4750382

Usually the symplectic gradient is not computed during integration, it is provided as function in code. In the separable case that is assumed here, one only needs to implement the force or acceleration function. Of course this only works if the system is really Hamiltonian, otherwise the method devolves into just another second order integrator.
The velocity Verlet method, which you are using, can be factored into two symplectic or semi-implicit Euler steps. Write the method in the two partial steps and time sorted
\begin{alignat}1
X_{i+1/2}&&&=X_i+ϵ/2V_i\\
V_{i+1/2}&+ϵ/2\nabla U(X_{i+1/2})&&=V_i
\end{alignat}
This gives for infinitesimal changes
$$
\pmatrix{I&0\\ϵ/2\,{\small\nabla\nabla^T} U(X_{i+1/2})&I}
\pmatrix{\Delta X_{i+1/2}\\ \Delta V_{i+1/2}}
=
\pmatrix{I&ϵ/2\\0&I}
\pmatrix{\Delta X_{i}\\ \Delta V_{i}}
$$
and in the second half-step
\begin{alignat}1
X_{i+1}&-ϵ/2V_{i+1}&&=X_{i+1/2}\\
V_{i+1}&&&=V_{i+1/2}-ϵ/2\nabla U(X_{i+1/2})
\end{alignat}
with infinitesimal relations
$$
\pmatrix{I&-ϵ/2\\0&I}
\pmatrix{\Delta X_{i+1}\\ \Delta V_{i+1}}
=
\pmatrix{I&0\\-ϵ/2\,{\small\nabla\nabla^T} U(X_{i+1/2})&I}
\pmatrix{\Delta X_{i+1/2}\\ \Delta V_{i+1/2}}
$$
All the matrices have determinant $1$, this remains also for their combination in the step $i\to i+1$.

Thanks a lot, this seems mostly logical to me and it helps a lot! I still wonder about your second step with the infinitesimal changes, isnt the matrix supposed to be "reversed", e.g I and 0 exchanged in the first row,...?

No, the first column is for the X changes, the second for the V changes. I see no error.

Ah you are right, my bad! Then one last question: Where does the nabla^T comes from? I think its only one time nabla?

This is a complicated way to write the Hessian of $U$. You need the Jacobian of the gradient of $U$ there, the symbols should be correct for that.
